# What is the design logic behind Fragments as static inner classes vs standalone public classes?

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments

I am not able to understand one important aspect of Android software design which I am just starting out with, from what I know `Fragment` design has been adopted in order to decouple the code, where the intuition is that the `Activity` remains as is and `Fragment` can be *reused* else where, maybe even in a different activity, or maybe along side other fragments, in something like a Master/Detail flow or landscape UI.

Okay so I have seen quite a handful of questions on SO asking as to why `Fragments` are placed as static inner classes within an `Activity` and the answer there is that if we do not make them static, the `Fragment` may hold a reference to the activity and something like a screen rotation or a re-draw might leak the activity or something.

This brings me back to square one and I have the question that, well, if the Fragment design has been adopted in order to decouple the code, then why are we marrying the `Fragment` to the `Activity` by putting it *inside* the activity class and not putting them as standalone public classes? Isn't that totally contradicting to the very existence of Fragments?

What is the down side of having a project structure as such? Where each `Fragment` is a separate class of its own? Given that my Fragment code can grow to like a 1000 lines especially when trying to do animations I am seeing this as far more neater, decoupled and reusable within activities other than it's intended parent Activity.

- Do we still suffer from the memory leak issue mentioned above?
- Am I missing something about the design logic? Please educate me.
- Is there a way where the Fragments stay as an inner class and still be used elsewhere? I might be missing something here as well... so do inform me.

[image: Project structure]

Any other project design methods, concepts, corrections to my intuition are more than welcome since I am just starting out here, I would love to know all my options.

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you please add a link to one of the answers advocating Fragments as static inner classes to Activities. It sounds like an absurd thing to do. I've always decoupled Fragments from Activities and had them in their own classes and .java files without any activity leakage or other such nonsense.

Comment: @britzl, say for example when ever you create a new activity in Android Studio, by default the Fragment (PlaceholderFragment) is embedded as a static inner class within the activity, I have to manually take it out from there and put it in its own class. That is default behaviour... which raised questions in my head.

Comment: Also here on the official documentation for Fragments. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design "public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment" under "Adding a user interface"

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed the "public static class" notation in the official docs. Anyway, in my mind Fragments should be treated as reusable pieces of UI, either for landscape vs portrait mode or for use in several different Activities. Sure, sometimes a fragment is used in only a single activity, but in such a case I'd question why it was ever made into a fragment in the first place.

Comment: @Akay You are right, the docs from google uses "public static class inside activity, in many samples" and fragments use terms like "fragment transactions" is ridiculous in fragment manager!!! i remember databases "commit" and "rollback" expressions. Really, i dont like android architecture, and architect team from google may be study design and patterns, because android for me is: Many codes lines for LESS results!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> This brings me back to square one and I have the question that, well, if the Fragment design has been adopted in order to decouple the code, then why are we marrying the Fragment to the Activity by putting it inside the activity class and not putting them as standalone public classes? Isn't that totally contradicting to the very existence of Fragments?

The main driver for fragments isn't decoupling but rather composition: reusable pieces of user interface that can be easily composed together in different configurations. From composability follows modularity and from it decoupling so yes, decoupling is there but it's not the primary concern.

Read on about [fragment design philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design).

The modularity coin has another side: if two things belong together such as an activity and a fragment that is only used with that activity, they are best kept together and not spread out all over the codebase so they are easier to evolve together. A project structure like in your question where activities and fragments are in separate packages would not really follow this principle.

One commonly seen way to keep fragments in separate classes but close to related activities and such is to use a naming prefix so they sort together in alphabetical lists within the same package: e.g. FooActivity with FooDetailsFragment.

For simple fragments where there isn't that much code and the fragment is only used in one activity, it's perfectly fine to have them as static inner classes in that activity.

Just try to be consistent so other people reading the code can easily find their way around in the codebase and the WTFs/minute code metric is kept low.

> Do we still suffer from the memory leak issue mentioned above?

No, the leak applies only to non-static inner classes that hold a reference to the outer class. Package-level classes do not have any outer class to held a reference to.

Since fragments share the hosting activity's lifecycle, leaking the outer object is not really the concern with fragments. It's just that the framework needs to be able to instantiate the fragments without any outer class objects, and `static` is a requirement for that.

> Is there a way where the Fragments stay as an inner class and still be used elsewhere? I might be missing something here as well... so do inform me.

You can refer to public inner classes with the dot notation `Outer.Inner` in code or `Outer$Inner` with reflection (e.g. XML files).

While this is technically possible, doing so says you're relying on the internals of a class and that's a design smell. I'd really refer to inner classes in the outer class code itself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to answer me, I really found it useful how you broke down each part of my question. One of the obvious reasons I asked this was because Android Studio is by default creating all my Fragments and static inner classes... I did not want to outsmart the default without knowing what I am doing. From your explanation I feel that Android Studio is making the assumption that the Fragment is only used for that particular Activity.

Comment: "I'd really refer to inner classes in the outer class code itself.", I'm having trouble understanding this part of your answer, what did you mean?

Comment: @Eddnav If you have `OuterClass.InnerFragment`, only use `InnerFragment` within `OuterClass`. Fragments should be modular; putting them inside some other class reduces modularity.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to better know the logic against your idea; I make Fragments in their own class all the time, and my apps run like a rock during reorients. I do use an interface to speak to the managing Activity, use adapters to manage the Fragments, and perform basic accounting to ensure I'm not launching several background threads from re-loading.

So I check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
which is always worth a re-read, and whaddya know, the example at the bottom is just what you suggest, and I use every day: two public fragments in stand-alone classes that are attached to and by an activity.

If someone is really suggesting what you say, I suspect they are taking the line "A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle." way, way too literally; they mean embedded in the runtime.

gl hf!

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comments, my source is Android Studio default behaviour and parts of the official docs. Though I find this informative "I do use an interface to speak to the managing Activity, use adapters to manage the Fragments, and perform basic accounting to ensure I'm not launching several background threads from re-loading." Have not tried doing that. Will see if it improves my practice.

Comment: Cool, yeah, don't be afraid to break out classes; speaking generally, being able to do that assures you that the object you are playing with is well formed and is doing what you think it is. Consider contract design patterns: in a perfect world, every object only works with the parameters in the constructor, static objects, and objects it creates. Fragments do a nice job of forcing this philosophy, and implementing interfaces is a great way to stay within the lines, but do things this + the class system prevents.