# When to use Static Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning about using fragments.

I see how dynamic fragments can be very useful.

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the appropriate time for static fragment use cases.

When are some typical scenarios when static fragments are used?

Comment: What do you mean by "static fragment" and "dynamic fragment"?

Comment: Static fragments are already coded into the xml of the activity. Whereas, dynamic fragments aren't. Dynamic fragments are added via the fragment manager/fragment transaction.

Comment: Read here about your static fragments 
- [Have a look:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190797/what-is-the-design-logic-behind-fragments-as-static-inner-classes-vs-standalone

Comment: @Spartacus It sounds like the OP is asking about "programatically creating fragments" vs. "creating fragments in XML"... not about when/why Fragments should be declared as `public static` classes.

Comment: Let me rephrase. "Programmatically adding fragments" to an activity is what I call dynamic fragments. "fragments" coded embeded into an activity xml using the "<fragment>" tag, is what I call static fragments. I'm simply asking what are appropriate scenarios where you would embed the fragment into the activity. Obviously, this fragment will not change in this activity. Perhaps, that same fragment is being added dynamically to the activities. Or even by embedded into other activity xml files. I'm simply just asking what are the commmon use cases for static embedded fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you declare your fragments in XML or instantiate them programmatically using the `FragmentManager` doesn't really make a difference... both approaches will end up doing the same exact thing under-the-hood. The main benefit of declaring `Fragment`s in XML is when you are dealing with multi-pane layouts. Instead of having to write a bunch of code to determine the device's current screen size and/or orientation, you can simply declare your multi-pane fragment layouts in XML, placing them in the appropriate resource layout bucket (i.e. `layout`, `layout-land`, `layout-sw600dp`, etc.).

Of course, you should not think of the ability to declare fragments in XML as a replacement for dealing with the `FragmentManager`. In many cases, you will likely need to deal with the `FragmentManager` either way, as `Fragment`s provide a ton of features that are only available  in code at runtime (i.e. back-stack management, `Fragment` transitions, etc.).