# LayoutInflator error "incompatible types" in fragment

Tags: java, android

[image]

```
Typeface hero = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Hero Light.otf");

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
   TextView tv=
  (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item_tab,null);
        tv.setTypeface(hero);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);

    }
```

I get an error at "this" saying incompatible types. Mainfragment cannot be converted to context.
Please help as this is the only working way for me to change fonts on my Tablayout.

Comment: if this code is in fragment then use `getActivity()` instead of this

Comment: The title of the question and body problem is different. Please not, Fragment is not inner class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190797/what-is-the-design-logic-behind-fragments-as-static-inner-classes-vs-standalone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is in Fragment then use getActivity() because here this will not work with inner class.

Answer (score 1):

**this** does not work in inner class. If it is fragment then try getActivity() and for activity try YourActivity.this

Answer (score 1):

This is how you change font. **Note:** I assumed the font you're using is compatible.

**First way:**

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(face);
```

**Second way:**

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL));
```

**Mainfragment cannot be converted to context**

replace with `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` for `getContext()`

To reach to the resource, you first reach to your Activity, where you have fragment setup by doing `getActivity()`. To get the same application context of your Activity, you do `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`